# Why is `dotnet new webapi` creating a different project for me than other people?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I'm following instructions from a tutorial. Using `dotnet new webapi` I'm getting a different project than the lesson shows and from another person's computer which I tested this on. We get mostly the same files but I have one extra `WeatherForcast.cs` and instead of the `ValuesController.cs` I get `WeatherForcastController.cs` with completely different code in it that I'll post at the bottom.

There are also some smaller differences in `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`

What accounts for this difference? How do I generate the files the way I'm trying, from the examples?

#### ANSWER : The answer is that it was defaulting to the .NET SDK 3.1 I have installed but this tutorial using .NET SDK 2.2. Running the command `dotnet new webapi --framework netcoreapp2.2` gives me the version of this webapi I'm looking for.

---

#### My controller `WeatherForcastController.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Testing.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example & other computer controller `ValuesController.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CretaceousPark.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check which version of .net core you are using. Likely the versions are different from the tutorial to what you have installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already pointed out in other answers, this is due to the difference in the SDKs being used.
Even if you have the same SDK installed, but have a newer one installed too, the newer SDK will be used by default.
You can, however, pin the SDK version to be used by the `dotnet new` command by adding a `global.json` file in the directory, where from you're running the command, with the following content:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Make sure to set the `version` value to the one from the tutorial.

You can read more about this behavior in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I knew there must be a good way to handle this. I discovered that
`dotnet new webapi --framework netcoreapp2.1` works as well

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the version of the .NET Core SDK you have installed.  If you want to follow the tutorial exactly, install that particular version.  And get rid of any version that is newer.  After you have learned from the tutorial, install the latest.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for the answer. I have both 2.2 and 3.1 installed on my machine, is there any way to add a version to use in the command like `dotnet new webapi -v 2.2.0` like when you add a package?

Comment: I found it, 2.2 doesn't work for some reason but running `dotnet new webapi --framework netcoreapp2.1` will install the version from this tutorial.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Because You have .net core 3.x SDK version on your computer and Other Computers that creating Values Controller have 2.x SDK.